# Visual Studio 2008 freezes when I edit XAML code

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

A few times a day my VS2008 SP1 freezes if I edit XAML code. It just got stuck and I have to kill the process.
It seems to be a problem with the IntelliSense or the spell-checking or whatever process is going on while I edit code.
The problem is very apparent if I copy+paste some code. Even if it is just one word. Many times VS2008 adds some additional commands in the code and messes things up completely.

This never happened with C# code only with XAML it does get stuck.

One more thing: It seems the problem only occurs when I edit control templates. I added a few control templates from the MSDN pages to my project. When I edit them - even doing simple things like changing brush colors - Visual Studio freezes (sometimes). So it seems it's not a general XAML problem it happens with control templates only.

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed?

Comment: Did you try using another VS2008 editor for XAML?

Answer (score 5):

You could try this update: [Installing DExplorer after VS 2008 breaks xaml intellisense](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=17287)

**EDIT:** You could try closing the **Properties** window when editing XAML, it helped me before with ASP.NET.

Some other links:

- [Xaml Editor Crashes after Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/61d52410-f101-4725-8a78-00c8d141cca8)
- [Using the Source Code Editor for XAML in Visual Studio](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Using_the_Source_Code_Editor_for_XAML_in_Visual_Studio.aspx)

Comment: Closing the Properties window seems to have helped greatly for me.

Answer (score 0):

After having this problem and hunting around on the interwebs I found this [vsnet-crashes-when-editing-xaml](http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.com/2009/05/vsnet-crashes-when-editing-xaml.html)

Which said, in summary, if you edit a xaml resource while something that uses said resource is open in a designer, then you'll be sorry.

So you can avoid the problem by

- Closing the other designer windows;
- Installing hotfix KB958017.